# Big-Theta notation

Tags: algorithm, proof

So I am new to all of this and looking for some help and guidance on proving a Big Theta notation.

```
Prove that log(3^3+ 2 + 17) = Θ(log(15^5+ 7^4 − 2))
```

I thought of simply raising both sides to the power of 2 and being left with the expressions themselves but I am not 100% this the right step towards the solution and I am honestly kind of lost.

I also know from the notation that I am looking for a solution that can satisfy the equation of:

```
c1(g(n))<=f(n)<=c2(g(n)), where c is a constant.
```

Comment: What is clog(f(x)) equivalent to using log rules?

Answer (score 1):

Easy to prove:

```
n^2 <3n^3 + 2n + 17 < 5n^5 + 7n^4 -2 < n^6 for n > 10 
=> 2 log(n) < log(3n^3 + 2n + 17) < log(5n^5 + 7n^4 -2) < log(n^6) = 6 log(n)
```

As both of `log(3n^3 + 2n + 17)` and  `log(5n^5 + 7n^4 -2)` are between a constant factor of `log(n)`, you can conclude that `log(3n^3 + 2n + 17) ⊂ Θ(log(5n^5 + 7n^4 -2))` and vice versa.